# What's the difference between VBoxContainer and VFlowContainer?

Tags: gui, ui-design, godot-4

I'm trying to build some UI for my game made in Godot 4.0. I want to make a "Toolbox" scene and need to decide what containers to use. I come from web development, where I'd use a `flex` `column` and each tool would be a single row in that column of items.

In Godot 4 I have many options, the two relevant ones are nearly indistinguishable:

- `VBoxContainer`

  - UI Description is "*Vertical box container.*"
  - [Official docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vboxcontainer.html) only say "*Vertical box container*" and tell me it has a `separation` property.
- `VFlowContainer`

  - UI Description is "*Vertical flow container.*"
  - [Official docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vflowcontainer.html) say "*Vertical flow container.*" and tell me it has both a `h_separation` and `v_separation` property

The control tree in the Godot UI has some hints. The icon for `VBoxContainer` suggests it's what I want, but then again it lists a `ColorPicker` as a child of that type of node so that throws me off again.

What's the difference between these two controls, and when would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, these are `Container`s. So they will resize and arrange their children `Control`s. Adjusting to both the space available and the size of the children (which I reiterate that the `Container` can resize, so pay attention to container sizing properties of its children, which used to be called size flags in Godot 3.x).

In particular:

- `VBoxContainer`: Will arrange the children `Control`s in rows. One per row. Might grow vertically.
- `HBoxContainer`: Will arrange the children `Control`s in columns. One per column. Might grow horizontally.
- `VFlowContainer`: Will arrange the children `Control`s in columns. As many as it can fit per column, i.e. one per row until it runs out of vertical space and then start a new column. It does not force vertical alignment or sizes (elements of different columns might not align). Might grow horizontally.
- `HFlowContainer`: Will arrange the children `Control`s in rows. As many as it can fit per row, i.e. one per column until it runs out of horizontal space and then starts a new row. It does not force horizontal alignment or sizes (elements of different rows might not align). Might grow vertically.
- `GridContainer`: Will arrange the children `Control`s in rows and columns. As many as configured per row. It controls spacing and position to make a grid. Might grow vertically.

You can put any of the mentioned `Container`s inside of a `ScrollContainer` to get scroll bars.

---

I also want to mention a couple specialized classes:

- `MenuBar`: It will make menu bars by adding children `PopupMenu`s. Good for non-game application. It does not flow. You could make menu bars or tool bars with `HFlowContainer` and children `MenuButton`.
- `Tree`: It will make a tree like the ones you see in FileSystem or Scene in the Godot editor. It cal also make tables with multiple columns, where each row is an item. You must populate it from code. Also, it handles it own scrolling.

---

I don't know what you mean by "Toolbox". However, given that you mention `flex column`, I would suggest `VFlowContainer`, which I remind you might result in more than one column… If you don't want that use `VBoxContainer` instead.

---

If you have a look at the `ColorPicker`, you will see that it is made by rows:

[image: ColorPicker in Godot editor designer]

The `ColorPicker` *is a* `VBoxContainer` so it gets to reuse all its logic.

For the curious, the first three rows are `HBoxContainer`, which is how they get multiple `Control`s in the same row. Then we have a `GridContainer` to make the color bars (made out of `Label`, `HSlider`, and `SpinBox`). The hex input is inside another `HBoxContainer`. And the "accordion"s on the bottom are `Button`s controlling the visibility of `GridContainer` for the color presets (which are also `Button`s).

Comment: Could you clarify what it means for the FlowContainers to "run out of space"? If they are allowed to resize in the same way BoxContainers are they will never run out of space.

Comment: @carllacan For example, `HFlowContainer` might grow vertically, but will not grow horizontally. So it will place its children `Control`s horizontally until it runs out of *horizontal* space, at which point it will start a new row. It is by adding a new row that it might grow vertically. In other words, `HFlowContainer` respects the horizontal size of the children, and its own horizontal size too.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear.