# Making a countdown time readout in Godot 3.1

Tags: timer, gdscript, godot-3

I wrote this script to design countdown in my game:

```
extends Container

export (int) var minutes = 0
export (int) var seconds = 0
var dsec = 0

func _physics_process(delta):

    if seconds > 0 and dsec <= 0 :
        seconds <= 1
        dsec = 10

    if minutes > 0 and seconds <= 0:
        minutes -= 1
        seconds = 60

    if seconds >= 10:
        $sec.set_text(str(seconds))
    else:
        $sec.set_text("0"+str(seconds))

    if dsec >= 10:
        $dsec.set_text(str(dsec))
    else:
        $dsec.set_text("0"+str(dsec))

    if minutes >= 10:
        $minutes.set_text(str(minutes))
    else:
        $minutes.set_text("0"+str(minutes))

func _on_Timer_timeout():
    dsec -= 1
```

Here's what the UI section looks like:

[image: UI node hierarchy]

When I play I get this error:

> Error: attempt to call function 'set_text' in base 'null instance' on a null instance.

Where is the problem with my script?

And I also wrote 00 in the text section of the `minutes` inspector, 00 in the `seconds` inspector, and 0 in the `dsec` inspector.

When I want to move them separately, I can't and they are all stacked on top of each other.

I want to know how I can move them so that 00:00:0 can be seen next to each other?

[image: Stacked text fields]

Comment: The picture shows that your don't have a `Node` with the name `minutes`, but you try to use it form code `$minutes`. Similarly you have a `Node` called `min` that you don't use. Which leads me to believe this is caused by a typo.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm guessing that OP only gets connectivity from a smartphone.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Thank you.
Now my scene is played, but it shows the seconds, minutes and dsec numbers on top of each other. I tried, it does not allow me to move each one separately. I put a picture of it.

Comment: I write correctly formatted code from a smartphone daily. The mobile version of the site has all the tools you need to write your code in a way that is legible to others, if you take time to do that. I've cleaned up the formatting this time, and corrected the image that you broke on your previous edit, but please take care in the future to check the post preview and ensure your post reads correctly before clicking the button to post it/save your edits.

Answer (score 1):

`Container`s control how the children nodes are positioned. The base `Container` class does nothing special, it simply leaves the children in a default position.

You could try a `HBoxContainer` if you want a `Container` that positions the children in a row (Please notice that you would require some control having the `":"`). *I describe how some of the `Container`s work [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/204805/10408).*

Or if you don't want the `Container` positioning the children, don't use a `Container`. `Control`s that are not `Container` can also have children, which would be positioned by their anchors and margins. *I have an explanation of the different ways things are positioned in Godot [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68460934/402022).*

*I would have tackled your problem with a single `Label` and `String` concatenation. See also [GDScript format strings](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_format_string.html).*

Comment: I edited everything you said.
In the inspector at containe,at variable scripts, I put  minutes = 0 and seconds = 60.
But when I play, the number of seconds stops at 60 and only the number of the dsec is continuously played from 0 to 10.
Seconds do not decrease ...

Comment: @NinaMonti *You can take a break, you can read your code.* I'd say it is probably this: `seconds <= 1`.